# rails Could not find devise-1.4.6 in any of the sources (trying to run rspec tests)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I try to run spec tests and I get

```
bundle exec rake spec
Could not find selenium-webdriver-2.6.0 in any of the sources
```

So I bundle and I get:

bundle
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find devise-1.4.6 in any of the sources

So I try to install devise 1.4.6 but I get

```
gem install devise -v1.4.6
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'devise' (= 1.4.6) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: devise
```

Which is really strange as my Gem file itself just has 'Devise' (**no** version number).

The rest of my Gem file is below.

I have also done rake test:prepare and the database and table exists in test.

```
cat Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rake', '0.9.2'
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'haml'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'devise'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'therubyracer'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
group :test, :development do
#  gem 'cucumber-rails', '0.5.0'
  gem 'capybara'#, '1.0.0.beta1'
  gem 'database_cleaner'#, '0.6.7'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.6"
#  gem 'forgery', '0.3.8'
  gem "forgery"
  gem 'factory_girl'#, '1.3.3'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'#, '1.0.1'
  gem 'shoulda'#, '2.11.3'
  gem 'rcov'
  gem 'turn', :require => false  # Pretty printed test output
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has been yanked, see [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise/versions):

```
1.4.6 September 19, 2011 yanked
```

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestion on alternative action I can take :)

Comment: I'd say: `gem install devise` would be fine :)

Comment: Unfortunately that's exactly the problem.  The devise install was ok (I got version 1.4.8) but still bundle wants devise 1.4.6 and still the Gemfile just says 'devise' with no '1.4.6' version anywhere in site.  Weird huh?  I can only assume that some other gem has that specific version dependency hidden somewhere!

Comment: omg YES.  That bundle lock file has caught me out a few times now!  Thanks Man, I have seen your other posts and was most glad to see you post this answer 'cos you are good.

Answer (score 1):

It is reading your Gemfile.lock so you need to run `bundle update`

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  That probably would work too but I went with apneadiving